# Error in SQL. Can not find it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Error in SQL. Can not find it.

```
DECLARE @year VARCHAR (4),
    @month VARCHAR (2),
    @day VARCHAR (2),
    @weekday VARCHAR (2),
    @hour VARCHAR (2),
    @archivePath VARCHAR (128),
    @archiveName VARCHAR (128),
    @archiveFullName VARCHAR (128)


SET @year = CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) 
SET @month = CAST(DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) 
SET @day = CAST(DATEPART(dd, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) 
SET @weekday = CAST(DATEPART (dw, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) 
SET @hour = CAST(DATEPART (hh, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
SET @archivePath = 'd:\1c_new\backupdb\'
SET @archiveName = 'TransactionLog_' + @year + '_' + @month + '_' + @day + '_' + @hour + '.bak'
SET @archiveFullName = @archivePath +  @archiveName

BACKUP LOG [xxx] TO  DISK = @archiveFullName WITH  INIT ,  NOUNLOAD , NAME = N'Ежечастный лог транкзаций',  SKIP ,  STATS = 10,  DESCRIPTION = N'Ежечастный лог транкзаций',  NOFORMAT
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  It would be more helpful for the people reading this question.

Comment: 3041 :
BACKUP failed to complete the command DECLARE @year VARCHAR (4),
 @month VARCHAR (2),
 @day VARCHAR (2),
 @weekday VARCHAR (2),
 @hour VARCHAR (2),
 @archivePath VARCHAR (128),
 @archiveName VARCHAR (128),
 @archiveFullName VARCHAR (128)


SET @year = CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())

Comment: What other error messages does it give you? [To determine why the BACKUP failed, examine the Microsoft SQL Server error log for any errors prior to error 3041.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238203%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch, try changing `N'Ежечастный лог транкзаций'` to something like `'NORMAL STRING'`